# Automatic next for Multi step form with Formik

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, formik, yup

I have a React Form Using Formik & Yup. The client needs it to move to the next step automatically after the user fills any input field. Do you have any ideas? articles or tutorials I can learn how to do it?

Comment: How will you know whether the user finished? Is your inputs are of fixed length?

Comment: Add two forms, and try to implement it and then post your question again, this way people can help you. Otherwise search in google "Formik multi step form"

Comment: @SanishJoseph Most of the forms are Radio inputs, but for the rest, I think I will need to call a function with every keystroke from the user. I know bad performance but I am looking for a better solution right now.

Comment: @windmaomao Thanks for your comment but I don't understand what do you mean with add 2 forms and try to implement it? kindly. can you clarify?

Comment: If your inputs are of a certain length and user must fill full length then moving to next control makes sense. As an example credit card number. It must be 16 digits. One finished we can move to next control. If the controls are of not fixed size I can’t think of a logical way to move to the next control.

Comment: @SanishJoseph No I have 1 txt input, 1 phone input, 1 checkboxes and the rest are Radio. So I think I only have a problem with text or the phone inputs.

Comment: Phone number can be of fixed length. Depending on what you are developing

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution is to use the `onInput` method to fire an event. But I think it is worth mention that most of my inputs were  Radio inputs so it was a suitable solution in this situation but it may be a bad performance for text, number or tel or any input that requires multi keystrokes. So consider this before using it.